# does Entity Framework support database views?

Tags: entity-framework

does Entity Framework support database views?

Comment: Here is a shorter way: [Frustrated by lack of support for SQL-Views in ADO.NET Entity-Framework Designer?](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/09/03/frustrated-by-lack-of-support-for-sql-views-in-ado-net-entity-framework-designer.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views).​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​